# Interdependent MySQL Calculation Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am currently developing a large MySQL database that has 4 main tables within it as follows:

**Table Damage Loop**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| Damage Loop No | Description | Minimum Remaining Life |
---------------------------------------------------------
| abc            | pie         | 5                      |
| xyz            | apple       | 15                     |
| ...            | ...         | ...                    |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**Table Equipment**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Damage Loop No | Equipment No | Description    | Minimum Remaining Life |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| abc            | X100         | pie slice 1    | 5                      |
| abc            | X200         | pie slice 2    | 20                     |
| xyz            | B100         | apple slice 1  | 15                     | 
| xyz            | B200         | apple slice 2  | 30                     |   
| ...            | ...          | ...            | ...                    |    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Table Monitoring Location**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Damage Loop No | Equipment No | CML No | Description | Corrosion Rate | Wall Thickness | Allowable Wall Thickness | Remaining Life |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| abc            | X100         | 1      | Location 1  | 0.2            | 3              | 2                        | 5
| abc            | X100         | 2      | Location 2  | 0.2            | 4              | 2                        | 10         
| xyz            | B100         | 1      | Location 1  | 0.2            | 5              | 2                        | 15
| xyz            | B100         | 2      | Location 2  | 0.2            | 6              | 2                        | 20    
| ...            | ...          | ...    | ...         | ...            | ...            | ...                      | ... 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Table Inspection**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Damage Loop No | Equipment No | CML No | Inspection No | Wall Thickness |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| abc            | X100         | 1      | 1             | 5              |
| abc            | X100         | 1      | 2             | 10             |
| abc            | X100         | 1      | 3             | 3              |
| ...            | ...          | ...    | ...           | ...            | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now these tables all have interdependent calculations that I would like to perform as triggers based on what values the user changes in the database. For example if we look at [Damage Loop].[Minimum Remaining Life]. It is calculated as follows...

```
[Damage Loop].[Minimum Remaining Life] = Min([Equipment].[Minimum Remaining Life] For Associated Records)
```

Where [Equipment].[Minimum Remaining Life] is calculated as follows...

```
[Equipment].[Minimum Remaining Life] = Min([Monitoring Location].[Remaining Life] For Associated Records)
```

Where the [Monitoring Location].[Remaining Life] is calculated as follows...

```
[Monitoring Location].[Remaining Life] = ([Wall Thickness] - [Allowable Wall Thickness])/[Corrosion Rate]

Where...
[Wall Thickness] = Min([Inspection].[Wall Thickness] for associated records)
[Allowable Wall Thickness] = Manual input
[Corrosion Rate] = Manual input
```

So if the user changes the [Monitoring Location].[Allowable Wall Thickness] field I would like the trigger to only recalculate the following fields...

```
[Monitoring Location].[Remaining Life]
[Equipment].[Remaining Life]
[Damage Loop].[Remaining Life]
```

But if the user changes the [Inspection].[Wall Thickness] field I would like the trigger to perform the following calculations...

```
[Monitoring Location].[Wall Thickness]
[Monitoring Location].[Remaining Life]
[Equipment].[Remaining Life]
[Damage Loop].[Remaining Life]
```

i.e. only re-calculate the fields that are **dependent** on the field the user changes.

I basically have hundreds of calculations like these in my system and would like a really efficient and structured way of only recalculating dependent fields based on what the user changes in the database. I would like to avoid having to write specific triggers for every possible case in the system. Any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Comment: As far as i knew, one trigger for one specific action only for each table which is update,insert and delete. So whats your plan? @Josh

Comment: My plan was to have two tables in my database. 1 to store the calculation string for all calculated fields and the other to store all field dependencies. I.e. a table that has two columns. Column 1 = Changed Field. Column 2 = Dependent fields. The trigger would lookup the [Changed Field] and return all [Dependent Fields]. These dependent fields would then be lookup up in the calculation table. The calculations would then be returned and executed. This would work if there was only one level (i.e. table) of dependency. The problem is how do I apply it to the next levels of dependency?

Comment: What do you mean next levels of dependency?

Comment: For example....[Monitoring Location].[Remaining Life] is dependent on  [Monitoring Location].[Wall Thickness]  and [Monitoring Location].[Allowable Wall Thickness] (Level 1). But then [Equipment].[Minimum Remaining Life] is dependent on [Monitoring Location].[Remaining Life] (Level 2) and then [Damage Loop].[Minimum Remaining Life] is dependent on  [Equipment].[Minimum Remaining Life] (Level 3)

Comment: You mean on update cascade.... on dependents table?

Comment: I don't believe so. I am not too experienced with this command but I believe Cascade is more in reference to keeping the primary and foreign keys aligned between the tables (as defined by the database schema). Not specific calculated fields as I am trying to achieve here.